# Lots of menuitems in delphi/lazarus

Tags: algorithm, delphi, lazarus

I have an application where I use a lot of hierarchical menuitems, each one has a text template associated with it. Everything is made at design time, so menuitems and text templates are constant. On the application, when choosing a menuitem, the relevant text template is inserted into a synedit control.

What would be a good approach to design this? My thinking is that inserting each menuitem through the IDE is cumbersome and not very friendly if I want to change/add/remove items, also, there are a lot of them..

Comment: You can add/edit/remove menu items manually in DFM file

Comment: @Krom - Since each menuitem is connected to a certain text object (template), I thought maybe using classes for the items would be better, but I don't know how to do it efficiently. Also maybe the text templates can be created as constant strings somehow.

Comment: You've specifically mentioned that nothing would change at run-time. So it's hard see what would make direct editing of the dfm inefficient. (If you even need to go that far.)  Menus are already fairly basic constructs. You can't do that much with them, and the designer is already quite efficient. Perhaps if we had a better understanding of how you use your text templates, your concern might make more sense.

Comment: @Craig - I edited the question to make it clearer. Essentially each meuitem inserts some text into synedit control.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly: Your menus could be represented by a bunch of name-value pairs; where name represents a caption, and value is a block of text? Add to that, you want your menus to be in a hierarchical sructure? Possibly multi-level?  ...... If so, and there are enough of them to justify it: I would probably store the data in a simple external file. Clearly identfy menu items with hierarchy info: E.g.: `#Menu: L1 Caption|L2 Caption|Leaf Caption`, followed by the text of its template. _You could embed the file as a resource into your app and it will be very easy to edit._

Comment: Building the menu dynamically based on the file should be fairly trivial.

Comment: @Craig - That sounds like a very good solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, here is what I ended up doing (as a full answer):

1. Created a text file with the templates of the text items to be inserted,   in no particular order. I can add to this file without too much thinking about order and logic in presenting the menus later on.
2. Wrote a python script that takes this raw file and creates a resource file, which is ordered with submenues and menuitems, on the lines of @Craig comment above. Optionally, it can create a D/LFM file to be loaded on compilation.
3. Include the .res file and write a small function on startup to dynamically create the menus (or optionally just include the D/LFM file).

**Edit**

Recently I tried to compile this on linux, it didn’t work… and it seems too ‘windowy’ anyways. So here is the updated version:

1. Same as 1 above.
2. Wrote a python script which takes this file and builds a unit with a collection and many collectionitems corresponding to the text items. The unit also has a function to populate the collection at runtime and a function to build runtime menus using the collectionitems.
3. When the program starts, first the collection is populated with all the collectionitems.
4. Every time a new editor window is opened, the “Insert text” menu is built dynamically from the collection.

This algorithm works great on windows and linux, is clean and easy to implement, plus no messing with D/LFM files, it is pure code.